# Черный экран elementary os

Tags: linux, elementary-os

Когда авторизуюсь в систему, вижу такую вот дичь. Игрался до этого со службами. До этого была проблема в том, что пропала панель сверху из-за того, что я отключил службу NetworkManager, ну я ее включил и теперь вижу это. Есть идеи как решить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Окно логина появляется?

Comment: Да, появляется.

Comment: Я не уверен насчёт elementary os, но во многих других дистрибутивах, на окне логина есть средства выбора оконного менеджера для сеанса, в котором Вы собираетесь работать. Какая-то выпадающая менюшка или ещё что-то. Попробуйте сменить оконный менеджер. KDE - > Gnome, или наоборот. Можно попробовать запустить LightDM. Этот легковесный менеджер, как правило, ставится во всех дистрибутивах.

Ну а если ничего не получится: Ctrl/Alt/F1 !!!